# Chrome extension - Background.html sendResponse to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've read countless answers here at Stockoverflow but none seem to be help me answer my question. Basically, here's my code:

### Background.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.method == "getIP") {

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var domain
        var ip = "bla";

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
            domain = tab.url;
            domainSplit = domain.match(/^[\w-]+:\/*\[?([\w\.:-]+)\]?(?::\d+)?/)[1];

            req.open (
                    "GET",
                    "http://colourpad.co.uk/projects/dub3helper/ip.php?" + domainSplit,
                    true);
                req.onreadystatechange = getIP;
                req.send(null);

                function getIP() {
                    if(req.readyState == 4) {
                        var ip = req.responseText;
                        alert (ip);
                        sendResponse({domainToIP: "Tester " + ip });    
                    }   
                }
            });             
        }
    else {
        sendResponse({}); //Snub them
    }

});
```

### Content script

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getIP"}, function(response) {
    $("p#versionNumber").append("<span>: " + response.domainToIP + "</span>");
});
```

The basics of the script work correctly, i.e. it does bring back the ip as the alert (ip); does fire with the correct ip data. The issue seems to be sending the ip variable to my content script. I think it may be a simple case of placing the sendResponse in the wrong place, but I really can't see why at the moment. I'm new to chrome extension development.

Any help is massively welcome, its driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the code was conflicted with another onRequest.addListener used on the background.html page. Fixed the issue by merging both separate listeners into one separated by a switch case:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    {
        switch (request.name)
        {
            case "getPreferences":
            // request from the content script to get the preferences.
            sendResponse(
                {
                    Bla : localStorage["bla"]
                });
            break;
            case "getIP":
            // Convert Domain to IP
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var domain
                var ip = "bla";

                domain = sender.tab.url;
                domainSplit = domain.match(/^[\w-]+:\/*\[?([\w\.:-]+)\]?(?::\d+)?/)[1];

                req.open (
                        "GET",
                        "http://colourpad.co.uk/projects/dub3helper/ip.php?" + domainSplit,
                        true);
                    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(req.readyState == 4) {
                            var ip = req.responseText;
                            sendResponse({domainToIP: ip });    
                        }   
                    }
                    req.send(null);
            break;
            default:
            sendResponse({});
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example worked fine for me. Maybe you are receiving response but your content script doesn't display it? Try `console.log(response)` instead of that jquery, and check console for both content script and background page, maybe there are some errors.

Couple suggestions about your background page:

Instead of:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    domain = tab.url;
    ...
});
```

You can use:

```
domain = sender.tab.url;
```

Instead of:

```
req.onreadystatechange = getIP;
function getIP() {
    ...
}
```

Try:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ...
}
```

**Update:**

Try closure:

```
req.onreadystatechange = (function(sendResponse) {
    return function () {
      if(req.readyState == 4) {
          ... 
      }   
  }
})(sendResponse);
```

Comment: Hi Serg, thanks for your fast reply and code clean up, much appreciated! Although, it still seems 'response.domainToIp' in the content script is undefined. Although 'response' has an object value of '__proto__'? No sure if that helps.

Comment: @Colourpad Strange, so the response is received but it is empty. Try sending simple `sendResponse({domainToIP: "Tester"});` instead, also try to put that line higher (before XMLHttpRequest), would it work?

Comment: @Serg - Yep it works correctly before the XML request. Also, through debugging and watching the ip value within the sendResponse - it does seem to take the correct value, but it doesn't seem to get sent to the content script for some reason?

Comment: @Serg Hmm I'm afraid not. Still doesn't want to do anything :/

Comment: Ah ha! Found the issue. Seems it was conflicting somehow with another onRequest.addListener on the background page. Makes sense looking back! Instead, I removed the above code and combined both listeners into one listener with a switch case and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help Serg!